# SimpleSAMLphp: is it possible to use an existing auth service for authentication?

Tags: saml, simplesamlphp

I'm trying to create a SAML IDP for the system I built. Probably I'm getting confused with concepts. My problem is as follows:

This system was built in SymfonyPHP which authentication is made by OAuth token. Nothing so special, the username and password are passed to the /auth endpoint and the request returns the token if the credentials are valid. It's working fine.

Now I have to integrate this credentials to a client system. Once the user is logged to my system, so it should be on the client side (like the "login with Google button). I've been searching and realized I should use SAML for that.

I installed the SimpleSAMLPHP and I'm trying to understand how to set it up as my IDP. Once it's made, I can create SPs for my clients systems.

Question: how to make the SimpleSAML use my existing service for authentication? Which module should I use?

Answer (score 1):

With SimpleSAMLPHP acting as an IdP, you want to have a look at [authentication modules](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-idp#section_2). The latter is a component that encapsulates the mechanics of signing into the identity provider. For example, if you were trying to sign in to the IdP with your Facebook account, SimpleSAMLPHP ships a [FB authentication module](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/authfacebook:authfacebook) that does this for you.

If your existing service can be supported by one of the SimpleSAMLPHP modules, then you're all set. Else, you need to develop your own module.

Comment: Thank you. I'll probably be exploring the module sgomez/simplesamlphp-module-oauth2. I think it may solve my problem.